# basis/injection vs canonical basis/injection

Tags: linear-algebra, definition

Let $\mathbb R^n$ (or $\mathbb C^n$) be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb C$).
Some texts in linear algebra used that there is a **canonical** basis of $V$. (Unfortunately, without mentioning specific definitions..)

My Questions:

> (1) What is a difference between canonical basis and just basis?  (Or what is a canonical basis? Is every basis is a canonical basis?)
>
> (2) What is a canonical injection? (My understanding is if $f:X\to Y$ is one-one function, we may say that $f$ is injective or $f$ is injection. Please correct me if I am wrong! Is every injection is a canonical injection?  I am wondering why do we need the word **canonical**? Any motivation?)

Just as an example: The book "Algebras of Linear Transformation" by Farenick, Douglas R.  uses the terms like canonical basis and canonical injections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have access to that book, but I find it *very* hard to believe that it says that every finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ has a canonical basis. The space $\mathbb{K}^n$ (where $\mathbb K$ is $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$) has a canonical basis:$$e_1=(1,0,0,\ldots,0),e_2=(0,1,0,\ldots,0),\ldots$$Also, the space $\mathbb{K}_n[x]$ of all polynomials in the variable $x$ whose degree is smaller thatn or equal to $n$ has a canonical basis: $1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^n$. But there is no general concept of canonical basis.

I am also not aware of a general concept of canonical injection. You must be missing something here.

Comment: @JCS: Thanks. The author  has mentioned that $\mathbb F^n$ where $\mathbb F$ is field, has a canonical basis... (Sorry for the mess..)

Comment: @JCS: I have edited the question. Also, he used the  word canonical basis by saying: $v: X\to \mathbb F(X): x\mapsto v(x)=v_x$, where $v_x(y)=1$ if $x=y$ and 0 otherwise is a canonical injection, where $\mathbb F(X)=$ the set of all functions on $X$ with finite support

Comment: @JCB: Is this standard? The motivation behind this is to construct free vector space. Thanks...

Comment: @Learner1 Yes, that's standard.

Comment: @JCS: Thanks. Is this just a customary to call canonical injection? Or the word canonical add some more meaning to injection?  Thanks..

Comment: It is clear to me that $v$ defined above is injection, but I am wondering why to use the word canonical...

Comment: @Learner1 I think it is usual, yes. It is called “canonical” because it is the standard way of identifying each element of $X$ with an element of $\mathbb{F}(X)$. It has nothing to do with being injective.

Comment: [Canonical injection](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Canonical_Injection_(Abstract_Algebra))

Comment: @Learner1 I cannot see how is this related to your question. We are *not* assuming that your set $X$ has some algebraic structure.

Comment: @JCS: All right, I got it now. Thanks a lot...

Comment: @JCS: Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Let's write vectors in $F^n$, where $F$ is a field, as rows (just for ease of typesetting them).

If $V$ is an $F$-vector space and $B=(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n)$ is a basis (together with an ordering, so we distinguish between bases where even just the order differ). We can define a map
$$
C_B\colon V\to F^n
$$
that maps each vector $v\in V$ to the (unique) vector $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)\in F^n$ such that
$$
v=\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\dots+\alpha_nv_n
$$
This is the *coordinate map* relative to the basis $B$ and $C_B(v)$ is the coordinate vector of $v$ (terminology is not universal). In other words
$$
C_B(v)=(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)
\quad\text{if and only if}\quad
v=\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\dots+\alpha_nv_n
$$
Such a map is a linear bijection.

Prove that if $B$ and $B'$ are different bases of $V$, then the coordinate maps $C_B$ and $C_{B'}$ differ.

If $V=F^n$ we might ask whether there exists a basis $E=(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ such that $C_E$ is the identity map. If such a basis exists, it is unique, and, indeed, it exists. Take
$$
e_1=(1,0,0,\dots,0),\quad
e_2=(0,1,0,\dots,0),\quad
\dots,\quad
e_n=(0,0,\dots,0,1)
$$
and consider that, when $B$ is a basis of $V$ as before, then
$$
C_B(v_1)=e_1,\quad
C_B(v_2)=e_2,\quad
\dots,\quad
C_B(v_n)=e_n
$$
so now the distinguished property of $E$ is evident.

This is why such a basis is called *canonical*: the coordinate vector of $v\in F^n$ relative to $E$ is the vector $v$ itself.

Such a concept is meaningless if $V$ is not $F^n$, because in this case $v$ and $C_B(v)$ live in different spaces.

---

The term *canonical injection* refers to a slightly different framework: if $U$ is a subspace of $V$, then the canonical injection is the (linear) map that sends each vector in $U$ to itself (as an element of $V$). In general there are several injective linear maps $U\to V$, and just one is “distinguished” and is thus called *canonical*.

---

**Personal note.** I beg to disagree with the other answer in the part where it claims that the space of polynomials of degree up to $n-1$ has a canonical basis. The basis $(1,x,x^2,\dots,x^{n-1})$ is an obvious choice, but it cannot be selected among other bases just by vector space properties, contrary to the canonical basis of $F^n$, at least not by “elementary” properties.